# ExtJS 5 spreadsheet selection model bug

Tags: excel, extjs, selection, spreadsheet, paste

There appears to be a bug with pasting partial selections into the grid as the row below my selection gets nulled out. I am using ExtJS 5.1.

I copied the following cells (2 rows and 2 cols)-

[image]

and pasted them in the ExtJS grid http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#spreadsheet

What I got was-

[image]

What could be the reason for the additional 3rd row (highlighted in red)? **Is there a workaround??**

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Override `putCellData()` of `Ext.grid.plugin.Clipboard` and delete the last row data. 
That will work.